# Google Analytics goals under-reporting conversions

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is this a known issue? For some reason Google Analytics goal completion numbers are much lower then what it should be, although the underlying data are correct:

1. I have a goal definition "Destination, begins with /goals/paid-digital-subscription/": 
   [goal definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJPaB.png)
2. The number of pageviews for this URL pattern (containing "/goals/paid-digital-subscription/") is 300. 
   [pageviews for matching the url patter is 300](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kFZP.png)
3. But the number of goals reported by GA is only 236.
   [goals reported is only 236](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoILk.png)

What is wrong? Why is goal completions significantly lower?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Goals in Google Analytics are counted once per session.